# Can't see background image on overlay

Tags: html, css, django

I have an overlay containing a django form and the background image doesn't show up. I have a silhouette image in the background and that fills the page, and ideally moves with the page size. Then a table on top in the centre of it containing my form which I have tried to make transparent.

I was blindly fiddling with the css yesterday and it has disappeared!

```
    {% extends 'prodman/basenew.html' %}
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% block pagetitle %}Time and Expenses{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}

    <iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hide"></iframe>
        <div id="overlay">
            <form id= "person-form" target='hiddenFrame' method = 'POST' action="" class="overlay-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                <table id="add-person-form" class="overlay-table">
                <tr></br></br>{{ personform.first_name }}</tr>
                <tr></br></br>{{ personform.surname }}</tr>
                <tr></br></br>{{ personform.email }}</tr>
                <tr></br></br>{{ personform.position }}</tr>
                <tr></br></br>{{ personform.contract_type }}</tr>
                <tr></br></br>{{ personform.mentor }}</tr>
                <tr></br></br><font color="white">Assign as a coach?&nbsp;</font>{{ personform.make_person_coach }}</tr>
                </table>
                </br>
                <input type = "submit" id = "save" value = "Add person">
                </br>
                </br>
                <strong>Click here to [<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>close</a>]</strong>
            </form>
        </div>

        <a href='#' class='class1' onclick='overlay()'>Add person</a>
<p>Some more html here....</p>
    {% endblock %}
```

In my basenew.html I have

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'tande/newtimesheets.css' %}" type='text/css' media='all'/>
</head>
```

...

Here is my stylesheet

```
#overlay {
     visibility: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 1000;
     background-image:url('{% static 'tande/images/silhouette.png' %}');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 90%;
     background-position: center;
}
#overlay div {
     width:800px;
     margin: 100px auto;
     background: #cccccc;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     padding:15px;
     text-align:center;
}
form.overlay-form {
     width:800px;
     margin: 350px auto;
}
table.overlay-table tr td {
    background: rgb(54, 25, 25); 
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, 0); 
    border-style: none;
    margin-right: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
}
add-person {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
body {
     height:100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
}
```

Just in case it's helpful here is how the overlay is triggered:

```
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your html and css are fine: https://jsfiddle.net/z7xxw84m/ My guess is that django can't access your stylesheet to render that {% static %}. When I work with background images in django I usually add an inline style tag in the html template `style="background-image: url({% static 'url' %});"`

Comment: @JonasGiuro just tried an inline style tag and that's worked, thanks! It's still strange how it was working yesterday in my stylesheet and it isn't now.... it looks a lot nicer without the inline. But thanks! :)

Comment: @Pete that shouldn't be a problem it works fine as an inline style tag!

Comment: mmmh, I think Pete might be right. Try this: `background-image:url("{% static 'tande/images/silhouette.png' %}");`

Comment: I've given that a go and taken the inline out and we're back to no background image!